# How to sort hash in ruby recursively

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a huge hash/json in below format. Sample is given.
How we can sort this result hash based on the "total" key in descending order?

Nb: The last level nested node will not have have `response` and `total` keys. They will have `metrics` as keys.

```rb
result = {
  "account_id_1": {
    "total": 1000,
    "response": {
      "location_1": {
        "total": 300,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 100} },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
        }
      },
      "location_2": {
        "total": 500,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 300 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 150 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      },
      "location_3": {
        "total": 200,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 75 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 75 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "account_id_2": {
    "total": 2000,
    "response": {
      "location_1": {
        "total": 300,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
        }
      },
      "location_2": {
        "total": 500,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 300 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 150 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      },
      "location_3": {
        "total": 1200,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 1075 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 75 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```rb
result = {
  "account_id_2": {
    "total": 2000,
    "response": {
      "location_3": {
        "total": 1200,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 1075 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 75 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      },
      "location_2": {
        "total": 500,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 300 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 150 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      },
      "location_1": {
        "total": 300,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "account_id_1": {
    "total": 1000,
    "response": {
      "location_2": {
        "total": 500,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 300 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 150 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      },
      "location_1": {
        "total": 300,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 100} },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
        }
      },
      "location_3": {
        "total": 200,
        "response": {
          "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 75 } },
          "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 75 } },
          "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 50 } },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would create a class to handle the custom sorting so that we can implement our own [`<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (Spaceship Operator)

Something like: (Working Example: https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/ThankfulAutomaticRam#main.rb)

```
class AccountLocaleMetricSorter
  include Comparable
  def self.sort(h)
    h.map do |name,values| 
      new(name: name, data: values)
    end.sort.reduce({}) {|m,o| m.merge(o.to_h)}
  end 

  attr_reader :name, :data, :o_data
  
  def initialize(name: , data: )
    @name = name 
    @o_data = data
    @data = parse_response(data)  
  end 
  
  def to_h
    return {name.to_sym => o_data} unless o_data.key?(:total)
    {name.to_sym => {
        total: o_data[:total],
        response: data.to_h
      }
    }
  end 
  
  def <=>(other)
    if o_data.key?(:total) && o_data.key?(:total)
      other.o_data[:total] <=> o_data[:total]
    elsif other.o_data.key?(:metrics) && o_data.key?(:metrics)
      other.o_data.dig(:metrics,:cost) <=> o_data.dig(:metrics,:cost) 
    else 
      0
    end 
  end

  private 
    def parse_response(response)
      return response unless response.key?(:response)
      self.class.sort(response[:response])
    end 
end
```

Usage as:

```
pp AccountLocaleMetricSorter.sort(result)
```

Output:

```
{:account_id_2=>
  {:total=>2000,
   :response=>
    {:location_3=>
      {:total=>1200,
       :response=>
        {:service_1=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>1075}},
         :service_2=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>75}},
         :service_3=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>50}}}},
     :location_2=>
      {:total=>500,
       :response=>
        {:service_1=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>300}},
         :service_2=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>150}},
         :service_3=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>50}}}},
     :location_1=>
      {:total=>300,
       :response=>
        {:service_1=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>100}},
         :service_2=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>100}},
         :service_3=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>100}}}}}},
 :account_id_1=>
  {:total=>1000,
   :response=>
    {:location_2=>
      {:total=>500,
       :response=>
        {:service_3=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>300}},
         :service_2=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>150}},
         :service_1=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>50}}}},
     :location_1=>
      {:total=>300,
       :response=>
        {:service_1=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>100}},
         :service_2=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>100}},
         :service_3=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>100}}}},
     :location_3=>
      {:total=>200,
       :response=>
        {:service_1=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>75}},
         :service_2=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>75}},
         :service_3=>{:metrics=>{:cost=>50}}}}}}}
```

Comment: can u explain what you are doing here exactly? with <=>
NB: this serves the purpose. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's first simplify your example.

```
result = {
  "account_id_1": {
    "total": 1000,
    "response": {
      "location_1": { "total": 300, "response": 1 },
      "location_2": { "total": 500, "response": 2 },
      "location_3": { "total": 200, "response": 3 }
    }
  },
  "account_id_2": {
    "total": 2000,
    "response": {
      "location_1": { "total": 300,  "response": 1 },
      "location_2": { "total": 500,  "response": 2 },
      "location_3": { "total": 1200, "response": 3 }
    }
  }
}
```

In your example,

```
result[:account_id_1][:response][:location_1][:response]
  #=> { "service_1": { "metrics": { "cost": 100} },
  #     "service_2": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } },
  #     "service_3": { "metrics": { "cost": 100 } } }
```

This value, and others like it, will remain unchanged, so I've replaced it with a placeholder, an arbitrary integer:

```
result[:account_id_1][:response][:location_1][:response]
  #=> 1
result[:account_id_1][:response][:location_2][:response]
  #=> 2
```

and so on.

---

I found it useful to create a helper method:

```
def sort_by_total_desc(h)
  h.sort_by { |_,g| -g[:total] }.to_h
end
```

The desired hash can then be computed as follows.

```
sort_by_total_desc(result.transform_values do |v|
  v.merge(response: sort_by_total_desc(v[:response]))
end)
  #=> {:account_id_2=>{
  #      :total=>2000,
  #      :response=>{
  #        :location_3=>{:total=>1200, :response=>3},
  #        :location_2=>{:total=>500, :response=>2},
  #        :location_1=>{:total=>300, :response=>1}
  #      }
  #    },
  #    :account_id_1=>{
  #      :total=>1000,
  #      :response=>{
  #        :location_2=>{:total=>500, :response=>2},
  #        :location_1=>{:total=>300, :response=>1},
  #        :location_3=>{:total=>200, :response=>3}
  #      }
  #    }
  #   }
```

---

Regarding the helper method, here is an example.

```
h = { "location_1": { "total": 300, "response": 1 },
      "location_2": { "total": 500, "response": 2 },
      "location_3": { "total": 200, "response": 3 } }
```

```
sort_by_total_desc(h)
  #=> {:location_2=>{:total=>500, :response=>2},
  #    :location_1=>{:total=>300, :response=>1},
  #    :location_3=>{:total=>200, :response=>3}}
```

which requires two steps:

```
a = h.sort_by { |_,g| -g[:total] }
  #=> [[:location_2, {:total=>500, :response=>2}],
  #    [:location_1, {:total=>300, :response=>1}],
  #    [:location_3, {:total=>200, :response=>3}]]
```

```
a.to_h
  #=> as above
```

---

The main method has two main steps. First perform the "inner" sorting.

```
h = result.transform_values do |v|
  v.merge(response: sort_by_total_desc(v[:response]))
end
  #=> {:account_id_1=>{
  #      :total=>1000,
  #      :response=>{
  #        :location_2=>{:total=>500, :response=>2},
  #        :location_1=>{:total=>300, :response=>1},
  #        :location_3=>{:total=>200, :response=>3}
  #      }
  #    },
  #    :account_id_2=>{
  #      :total=>2000,
  #      :response=>{
  #        :location_3=>{:total=>1200, :response=>3},
  #        :location_2=>{:total=>500, :response=>2},
  #        :location_1=>{:total=>300, :response=>1}
  #      }
  #    }
  #   }
```

Then do the "outer" sorting to return the desired result:

```
sort_by_total_desc(h)
  #=> as above
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

Comment: Beautiful and succinct as always (the code not the verbosity of the explanation), I just wasn't sure whether or not sorting "metrics" was a requirement. Additionally I always question why a Hash needs to be sorted but...

Comment: @engineersmnky, as I was finishing my answer I had the same thought about whether "metrics" was to be sorted, but I did not have the energy or time to address that. I have encountered a few situations where I was able to exploit the fact that keys in hashes remain in insertion order, but they have been about as rare as [hen's teeth](https://www.myenglishpages.com/english/random-idiom.php?c=1155).

Comment: metrics need not to be sorted. metrics is already getting as sorted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland SO this requires two levels of sorting? I just given this as an example. I can have many such levels, So if I have 5 levels, how do i manage this?

Comment: I can't give you a complete answer about sorting five or an arbitrary number of levels but I expect one would employ a method recursively. If you wish to explore that further you could post a second question, but you might first consider whether any key-value pairs actually need be sorted, as opposed to sorting values of interest after they have been extracted from the hash. It is, after all, highly unusual to worry about key order in a hash.